# UnsupportedCharsetException: utf-lixo

Tags: php, android, utf-8

I am getting this error on Logcat when I try to run an Activity in my APP.

```
1134-1134/br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm, PID: 1134
    java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: utf-lixo
```

I have Debugged the code and everything works fine until I call a webservice

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_info_hospital,"GET",params);
```

The PHP page is working and all information needed is ok.

I have checked both PHP and APP code and I did not find **UTF-lixo**

On App layouts all are using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

And the PHP isn´t declaring anything.

Below is the full code of the activity

```
package br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HospitalActivity extends Activity {

TextView Nome;
String pid;
Button btnIndicarLotacao;


// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// URL de busca de informações hospital
    private static final String url_info_hospital = "http://www.quickmed.com.br/android_hospital.php";

// JSON Nodes names

    private static final String TAG_HOSPITAL = "hospital";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NOME = "nome";
    private static final String TAG_SUCESSO = "sucesso";
    private static final String TAG_LOTACAO = "lotacao";

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hospital);

    //Botão de Indicar Lotação
    btnIndicarLotacao = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnIndicarLotacao);

    //Buscando detalhes do hospital através do Intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Buscando o pid do intent
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    // Buscando info do hospital no background
    new InfoHospital().execute();

    // Botão Indicar Lotação
    btnIndicarLotacao .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            //Launch atividade Lista de Hospitais
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ListagemHospitaisActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
    /**
     * Background Async Task para buscar todos as informações do hospital
     */

    class InfoHospital extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        /**
         * Mostra Progress Dialog
         */

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HospitalActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Carregando informações dos hospitais. Favor aguadar ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * Buscando as informações num Background thread
         */

        protected String doInBackground(String... params){

            //atualizando UI pelo Background thread

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Check for sucesso tag
                    int sucesso;
                    try {
                        //Construindo Parametros
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid",pid));

                        //buscando as informações do produto atrav~es de Request HTTP
                        // Observer que o url de buscar produtos vai utilizar GET
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_info_hospital,"GET",params);

                        // Verifica o log para a json response
                        Log.d("Info Hospital", json.toString());

                        // json tag sucesso
                        //sucesso = json.getInt(TAG_SUCESSO);

                        sucesso = 1;

                        if (sucesso == 1){
                            // Recebeu informações do Hospital
                            JSONArray hospitalObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_HOSPITAL);

                            JSONObject hospital = hospitalObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            //produto encontrado
                            // TextView
                            Nome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayNome);
                            Nome.setText(hospital.getString(TAG_NOME));


                        }else{
                            // hospital não encontrado
                        }

                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

          return null;
        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see `JSONParser` in the import list. Is it a custom implementation? Have you tried to test it in isolation?

Comment: @spaceCamel is a somewhat custom implementation. I followed a tutorial posted online http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/   making a bunch of alterations.

This would be a alternate version on item 10

As for `JSONParser` The original code does not have it, my other activity that does a similar thing does not have it and I tried to import it and the other org.json.JSON ... are Stringer and Tokener

As to test in isolation, I will be honest, I quite don't understand what that means.

Thanks for you time.

Comment: with "to test in isolation" I meant running a minimal piece of code that runs your `JSONParser` with given parameters and checks that the result is what you expect. In general a unit-testing framework is used for this purpose. Have you ever heard of [JUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit)?

Comment: @spaceCamel I managed to find the error, it was a silly problem in the JSONParser class. 

But I do thank you for your comment, it was it the set me on the track to analyse the JSONParser class.

As the test in isolation, I never heard of JUnit until now, but I will sure check it out.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake. But I will leave it here so it may help other with the same silly mistake. On the `JSONParser` class, it defines the `URLEncodedUtils`. The error was there.

Instead of UTF-8 it was utf-lixo on the 4th line of the block below

```
}else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "UTF-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
```